# Why can't I change the console title?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, native

I'm currently doing an assignment in which I have to call C functions from Java. I'm currently unable to change the console title.
This is the C method in which the console title gets changed:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Native.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Native_setConsoleTitle(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring title)
{
    const char *strTitle;
    strTitle = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, title, NULL);
    SetConsoleTitle(_T(strTitle));
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, title, strTitle);
}
```

The problem is, the title of the console doesn't change at all. It says "command prompt" like always. And I don't get any compilation errors. Any ideas?

Comment: C does not support _methods_.

Comment: This _T thing is obsolete. Win32 uses UTF-16; Java does too. Why don't you? Some error checking can answer better than we can speculate: Both JNI and Win32's GetLastError.